# Karate UI: Javascript dropdown not getting clicked

Tags: karate

```
Scenario: Sample scenario

 Given driver 'https://material-ui.com/components/selects/'
 * delay(5000)
 * scroll("//div[@id='demo-simple-select']")
 * click('#demo-simple-select')
 * click("//div[@id='demo-simple-select']")
 * Karate.stop(500)
```

**Note:** Here there is no native or traditional dropdown.Javascript/Material UI dropdown is used.

Comment: this question does not help anyone. follow this process if you can, or try to figure this out on your own: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/develop/examples/ui-test

Comment: Hi Peter, my query is specific to javascript/material ui dropdown and not related to native/traditional dropdown. In the earlier similar thread(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61798732/karate-ui-drop-down-handling) your solutions works since it's traditional dropdown if you check the HTMLattached to that thread. if you check https://material-ui.com/components/selects/   there are non traditional dropdown which not getting clicked using karate commands like click/select/script(). In my project similar material ui is used. Happy to be advised for the solution. Thanks.

Comment: I don't know anything about material ui. karate can handle html / js if you know what to do. your question has zero detail that helps answer, it can be re-opened if you edit your q. but I repeat, in my opinion, the only way you can get an answer is to follow the process in my link above. all the best

Comment: Hi Peter, sorry for the trouble. For live example I can not share project html page/code because of company policy. But yes for live example please check url (https://material-ui.com/components/selects/)

Under "Simple Select" heading section, there are many dropdowns(Material UI) as an example. Please pick the first one, for which <select> html tag is not used, so it's not a traditional dropdown. In our project we have used EXACTLY same one which I tried to click using Karate command click/select/scripts(), but no success. Could you please help me here? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `mouse()` and `input()` for e.g.

```
* mouse('#demo-simple-select').click()
* input('body', Key.ENTER)
```

If all this fails, try JS: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60800181/143475

Note that for "native" select boxes, use `select()`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61803260/143475